# How can I create an inline navbar where a header is positioned left and the links are positioned right?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to replicate this, positionally:

[image]

But my code returns a misaligned group of elements, like so:

[image]

Here is my code:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-2 col-sm-offset-2">
        <h4 style="color: white">Quietgym</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-4">
        <ul class="list-inline" style="color: white">
            <li><a>Today</a></li>
            <li><a>This Week</a></li>
            <li><a>Overall</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you paste your CSS?

Comment: What version of Bootstrap? FWIW I think they all need the navbar to be a <nav> not a <div>.

Answer (score 0):

Try navbar class

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
     <div class="container">
         <div class="navbar-header">
             <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Quietgym</a>
         </div>
         <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
             <li><a href="#">Today</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">This Week</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">Overall</a></li>
         </ul>
   </div>
</nav>
```

This snippet has been take from bootstrap document [here](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar).
Bootstrap comes with a pre-built css class for building responsive navigation bars.
You can also use w3schools navbar tutorial [here](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_navbar.asp).

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, including an explanation of *how* and *why* this solves the problem [would really help](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now!  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.